# Regular expression puzzle

Tags: regex, puzzle

This is not homework, but an old exam question. I am curious to see the answer.

We are given an alphabet S={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,+}. Define the language L as the set of strings w from this alphabet such that w is in L if:

a) w is a number such as 42 *or* w is the (finite) sum of numbers such as 34 + 16 or 34 + 2 + 10

and

b) The number represented by w is divisible by 3.

Write a regular expression (and a DFA) for L.

Comment: What language is this resulting answer expected to be written in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
^(?:0|(?:(?:[369]|[147](?:0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[147]0*(?:\+?(?:0\
+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[258])*(?:0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[258]|0*(?:
\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[147]0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[147])|[
258](?:0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[258]0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0
\+)*[147])*(?:0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[147]|0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)
*\+?(?:0\+)*[258]0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[258]))0*)+)(?:\+(?:0|(?:(?
:[369]|[147](?:0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[147]0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)
*\+?(?:0\+)*[258])*(?:0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[258]|0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*
[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[147]0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[147])|[258](?:0*(?
:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[258]0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[147])*
(?:0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[147]|0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)
*[258]0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*[258]))0*)+))*$
```

It works by having three states representing the sum of the digits so far modulo 3. It disallows leading zeros on numbers, and plus signs at the start and end of the string, as well as two consecutive plus signs.

Generation of regular expression and test bed:

```
a = r'0*(?:\+?(?:0\+)*[369]0*)*\+?(?:0\+)*'
b = r'a[147]'
c = r'a[258]'

r1 = '[369]|[147](?:bc)*(?:c|bb)|[258](?:cb)*(?:b|cc)'
r2 = '(?:0|(?:(?:' + r1 + ')0*)+)'
r3 = '^' + r2 + r'(?:\+' + r2 + ')*$'
r = r3.replace('b', b).replace('c', c).replace('a', a)

print r

# Test on 10000 examples.

import random, re
random.seed(1)
r = re.compile(r)
for _ in range(10000):
    x = ''.join(random.choice('0123456789+') for j in range(random.randint(1,50)))
    if re.search(r'(?:\+|^)(?:\+|0[0-9])|\+$', x):
        valid = False
    else:
        valid = eval(x) % 3 == 0
    result = re.match(r, x) is not None
    if result != valid:
        print 'Failed for ' + x
```

Comment: A tear just trickled down my cheek... :P I love RegExp doing Math Stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Note that my memory of DFA syntax is woefully out of date, so my answer is undoubtedly a little broken.  Hopefully this gives you a general idea.  I've chosen to ignore `+` completely.  As AmirW states, abc+def and abcdef are the same for divisibility purposes.

Accept state is C.

```
A=1,4,7,BB,AC,CA  
B=2,5,8,AA,BC,CB  
C=0,3,6,9,AB,BA,CC
```

Notice that the above language uses all 9 possible ABC pairings.  It will always end at either A,B,or C, and the fact that every variable use is paired means that each iteration of processing will shorten the string of variables.

Example:

```
1490 = AACC = BCC = BC = B (Fail)  
1491 = AACA = BCA = BA = C  (Success)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a full solution, just an idea:

(B) alone: The "plus" signs don't matter here.  `abc + def` is the same as `abcdef` for the sake of divisibility by 3. For the latter case, there is a regexp here: http://blog.vkistudios.com/index.cfm/2008/12/30/Regular-Expression-to-determine-if-a-base-10-number-is-divisible-by-3

to combine this with requirement (A), we can take the solution of (B) and modify it:

- First read character must be in 0..9 (not a plus)
- Input must not end with a plus, so: Duplicate each state (will use `S` for the original state and `S'` for the duplicate to distinguish between them). If we're in state `S` and we read a plus we'll move to `S'`.
- When reading a number we'll go to the new state as if we were in `S`.  `S'` states cannot accept (another) plus.
- Also, `S'` is not "accept state" even if `S` is. (because input must not end with a plus).